# Redirect directory to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my domain pointed to a Rails app in Heroku, so for example, when you wanted to access some video, you would have an URL such as:

`http://codigofacilito.com/video/W53XHWkbz34`

We need to change that app to a subdomain, so the updated version would be:

`http://videos.codigofacilito.com/video/W53XHWkbz34`

What I want to know is:

Is there a way to redirect people to the new url with the subdomain videos by using the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need this rule to only be applied to the video route, then give the following a try:

In your document root's `.htaccess` file, insert the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(video/.*)$ http://videos.codigofacilito.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Just `RewriteRule ^(video/.*)$ http://videos.codigofacilito.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]` is enough. No need of RewriteCond also.

Comment: Just what I needed, and it was good for other controllers that I have in the Rails app.
Thank you very much, and as anubhava says it was enough with the RewriteRule

Answer (score 8):

This works for me

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/xxx/(.*)$ http://xxx.domain.com/$1
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [mod_alias](//httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect permanent /video http://videos.codigofacilito.com/video
```

The keyword `permanent` causes Apache to send an HTTP status of `301 Moved Permanently` instead of `302 Found`.

Comment: This solution helped me out today! The quirk is that `RewriteEngine` will continue to be processed even when redirected.