# Redirect to subdomain with condition check

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain :

```
example.com
```

with subdomain :

```
blog.example.com
```

Initially all the blogs where handled in main domain rather with subdomain.But now i have moved them to a folder "blog".

And earlier blog links where as :

```
example.com/123/blogcontent1
example.com/458/blogcontent2
.......
.......
example.com/458/blogcontentn
```

> My question is how to write htaccess rule so that , whenever domain
>   name / "numeric"  appends redirect them to subdomain say as below
>   example :

```
example.com/123/blogcontent1   ->  blog.example.com/123/blogcontent1
example.com/458/blogcontent2   ->  blog.example.com/458/blogcontent2
```

Also ,
I have already checked following posts , **but they are not conditional ones** as my problem stated ,

[Redirect directory to a subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712358/redirect-directory-to-a-subdomain)

[How do I redirect domain to subdomain using htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031341/how-do-i-redirect-domain-to-subdomain-using-htaccess)

*It would be of great use if any help.Thanks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess of `example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^\d+/ http://blog.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: but its taking %7d with blog.example.com , blog.example.com%7D/880/blogcontent1

Comment: there was an extra curly brackets which resulted in %7 thank you anubhava..

Comment: Thanks so much @utility for correcting my typo error